# My VS Code is not opening, even though it s open in task manager

Tags: visual-studio-code

I opened up VS Code to do some NextJS, but in the process realized that my VS wont open. I checked in task manager and it was open. I dont know what to do

I tried to first looked at my event viewer to see if any errors were coming when i launched VS Code. Turns out i filtered for "Errors" and "Warnings" and i fount over 2000 Errors + Warnings. I dont know how to fix this.

Comment: Maybe try posting on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: try running `code --verbose` in a terminal and show us what you see